# Finding the second occurrence of a pattern in a string swift

Tags: regex, swift, pattern-matching

I'm trying to find two phone numbers in a string, have the first one in "phone" and the second one in "secondPhone". I'm trying to find the second phone number by using *? but it's not working, can anyone help?
there was some answers about it in java php python ... but I didn't find anything in swift!

```
let phone = note.rangeOfString("((1(-|\\s)?)?\\d{3}(-|\\s)?\\d{3}(-|\\s)?\\d{4})|((1(-|\\s)?)?\\(\\d{3}\\)\\d{3}(-|\\s)?\\d{4})", options:.RegularExpressionSearch)

let secondPhone = note.rangeOfString("((1(-|\\s)?)?\\d{3}(-|\\s)?\\d{3}(-|\\s)?\\d{4})|((1(-|\\s)?)?\\(\\d{3}\\)\\d{3}(-|\\s)?\\d{4})*?(((1(-|\\s)?)?\\d{3}(-|\\s)?\\d{3}(-|\\s)?\\d{4})|((1(-|\\s)?)?\\(\\d{3}\\)\\d{3}(-|\\s)?\\d{4}))", options:.RegularExpressionSearch)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if phone.rangeOfString(phoneNumberString, options: nil) != nil {
    //contains phone number
}
```

Just have `phoneNumberString` be your phone number as a string.

Comment: I don't get it, why "phone.rangeOfString"? the text that I'm searching in it, is "note"

Comment: The rangeOfString function basically returns nil if the string given, in your case "note", is not inside the string it's looking at, in your case the phone number. It returns the range of the string as a NSRange (hence the name) if it finds that string.